# Show Edit tag in SharePoint list

Tags: list

I have a SharePoint list and when a new record is added it shows a tag that says "new." Is there anyway to show "Edit" tag when a list is modified?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? what is the scenario?

Comment: If you look at this image http://i.imgur.com/HNzBuZ0.png It will show Customer and when a new record is added it shows up as new. I want to know if you modify a record and click save. Is there a way to show "Edited?"

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by adding some JavaScript to the page where you are rendering the list. If your SharePoint version is above 2013 or online you can do it by adding CSR.

The logic you man need is if Modified date is less than your required number days (you want to show the Edited flag for 2 days after modified)

```
<<Today date>> - <<Modified date>> < 2
```

then append a small HTML code to the title

```
<span style="color: blue"> edited</span>
```

Let me know which version of SharePoint you are using I will provide snippet.

This snippet works if you are using jQuery

`var dateColIndex = 6;
$(".ms-listviewtable tbody tr").each(function(index){
            var strDate = $(this).find("td:eq(" + dateColIndex + ")").text();
            var days = Math.round((new Date() - new Date(strDate))/1000/60/60/24);
            if(days < 5) {
                $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").append("edited");
            }
        });`

It display as follows
[image]

Comment: Update with code which has been tested with 2013 hope should work with 2010 also. You should add a content editor web part and script.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Calculated Column

```
=IF( [Modified] > [Created] , "Edited" ,"" )
```

Comment: Thank you! They actually don't want a new column. If nothing else can be done I will go with this.

Comment: Then your only option is to add JavaScript in a CEWP (or UserCustomAction) and proces the DOM structure... that's senior JavaScripting